# RDS MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user when connecting to db from EC2

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have an EC2 instance that I am trying to connect to an RDS (mySQL) instance.

I created an RDS mySQL instance with the name: `mydbinstance`, user: `mysuperuser` and a generic 8 character (`mypassword`) just for testing purpose.

> Virtual Private Cloud: **default**
>   (same as where the EC2 is located)
>
> Subnet group: **default**
>
> Public accessibility: **No** (*DB instance will not have a public IP
>   address assigned. No EC2 instance or devices outside of the VPC will
>   be able to connect.*)
>
> Availability zone: **No preference**
>
> VPC security groups: **Create new VPC security group**
>
> IAM DB authentication: Disabled

I added the RDS instance to the same VPC as the EC2 instance, so it's in the same zone.

The dbinstance is using a new security group:

> Type: Custom TCP Rule Protocol: TCP Port: 3306 CIDR: 174.62.127.135/32

Where does this IP address comes from? I didn't specify anything at instantiation...

Next, I ssh to my EC2 instance (the one located in the same VPC), and try:

```
$ mysql -h mydbinstance.$(RDS_INSTANCE).us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u mymasteruser -p
```

I entered `mypassword` (the one I specified earlier) at the prompt and I get:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'mymasteruser'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES)

I tried getting the IP address of the EC2 box with `ifconfig`, and updated the security group IP address (the one I was wondering about above) used by RDS with it. Same result, no luck connecting. I've been googling for an answer since then.

What are my other options to debug this? I would appreciate any suggestions.

**UPDATE**

I was able to run this from my laptop (by changing the DB `Public Access` to `YES`):

```
mysql -h mydbinstance.$(RDS_INSTANCE).us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u mymasteruser -p
```

> found 0 associations found 1 connections:

```
found 0 associations
found 1 connections:
     1: flags=82<CONNECTED,PREFERRED>
    outif en3
    src 192.168.86.33 port 55863
    dst xx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 3306
    rank info not available
    TCP aux info available
```

But I am unable to get any output from my EC2 instance. It hangs! Same why I run netcat (nc) command. Why is this not working on my EC2 instance?

Comment: Chech the security group that it allows this connection.

Comment: I did. I wrote above: The dbinstance is using a new security group: and provided the parameters for it.

Comment: If the security group didn't let me in, i wouldn't see the mySQL error. I suspect credentials are wrong but I triple checked why I typed, so I can scratch this. Is there another command I can try to use to connect from EC2 to RDS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to make it work after I found the nugget on the aws forum. Posting it back here in case someone stumble on the same issue:

> "In order to connect to MySQL, you will have to authorize the IP
>   address of the host from which you plan to connect to MySQL. You
>   should also revoke access from the CIDR you currently have authorized.
>   If you don’t know your computer’s IP address, you can see it by
>   visiting the site http://checkip.amazonaws.com/. Note that you will
>   have to add “/32” to the end of this to convert the IP address to a
>   CIDR which contains only that IP address. For example, if your IP
>   address is 192.0.2.10, you should authorize access to the CIDR
>   192.0.2.10/32.

Comment: This answer isn't clear enough. Authorize the ip address of the host.. where? Revoke access... where?

Comment: In "Inbound rules" for "Security group", which is linked to your RDS instance.

Comment: ^ the above setting can be found in EC2 > security groups. NOT RDS ... confusingly!

Comment: In RDS there is current a "connectivity and security" tab. Click to edit the "VPC security group" the click on the link under the "security group ID" column you can then "edit inbound rules"

Comment: What if the host doesn't have static public IP?

Comment: This is not a good answer and does not suit most of the cloud application setup. Given most basic configuration: an autoscaling group of EC2 instances running a backend application that needs access to a DB. Each instance has its own IP and as the group scales out/in, the IPs will change. So the correct way should be to set the DB security group inbound rules to allow inbound traffic from the security group associated with the auto-scaling group.